# How can I get consistent vertical spacing between \multicols{3} and \multicols{1}?

Tags: spacing, multicol

As you can see in the image, the vertical spacing is inconsistent.

[image]

I would like to avoid hacking my way into simulating the spacing that multicol uses.

If I use \multicols{1}, I get the warning:

> Package multicol Warning: Using `1' columns doesn't seem a good idea. 
>   I therefore use two columns instead on input line 20.

What is a good way to get symmetric vertical spacing in this example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,times}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{multicols}{3}
    \centering {\bfseries Title 1} \\
    \centering Description 1 \\
\columnbreak
    \centering {\bfseries Title 2} \\
    \centering Description 2 \\
\columnbreak
    \centering {\bfseries Title 3} \\
    \centering Description 3
\end{multicols}
\hrule
% \begin{multicols}{1}
    \centering {\bfseries Title 4} \\
    \centering Description 4
% \end{multicols}
\hrule
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \centering {\bfseries Title 5} \\
    \centering Description 5 \\
\columnbreak
    \centering {\bfseries Title 6} \\
    \centering Description 5
\end{multicols}
\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: The assumption is that you're generating a much larger (multi-page) document and you're just testing the heading spacing, right? Otherwise a tabular would be fine for presenting the information listed in your example.

Comment: You are suggesting to use tabular instead of multicols, not instead of (sub)sections. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure about the bigger picture for your document. What content will be used between the headings? For example, your three-column `Title 1`, `Title 2` and `Title 3`: will there be three-column text below that that should break across the page boundary? Another alternative would be to use a 3-column `multicol` for your single centred `Title 4`, leaving some empty content in column 1 with a `\columnbreak.

Comment: Say there is no big picture. How would you modify the code I provided so that the vertical spacing is consistent?

Comment: I have now simplified the question by removing memoir, replacing sections with hrules, and adding an image.

Comment: Try using `\bigskip` on either end of your 'one column' section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following provides a consistent spacing - you have to make to use the same code for vertical spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

%----------
% Sections
%----------
\newcommand{\mysec}[2][2]{%
  \LARGE\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{Y}}
    #2
  \end{tabularx}%
  \bigskip
}

\newcommand{\mysubsec}[2][3]{
  \Large\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{Y}}
    #2
  \end{tabularx}%
  \medskip
}

\newcommand{\mysubsubsec}[2][4]{
  \small\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{Y}}
    #2
  \end{tabularx}%
  \smallskip
}

\begin{document}

\mysec{\bfseries Heading}

\mysubsec{\bfseries Subheading 1}

\mysubsubsec[3]{%
  {\bfseries Title 1} \par Description 1 &
  {\bfseries Title 2} \par Description 2 &
  {\bfseries Title 3} \par Description 3
}

\mysubsec{\bfseries Subheading 2}

\mysubsubsec{%
  {\bfseries Title 4} \par Description 4
}

\mysubsec{\bfseries Subheading 3}

\mysubsubsec[2]{%
  {\bfseries Title 5} \par Description 5 &
  {\bfseries Title 6} \par Description 6
}

\end{document}​
```

I've used a full-width [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) which puts a number of `Y`-columns (defined as centred `X`-columns). `\mysec` is followed by `\bigskip`, `\mysubsec` by `\medskip` and `\mysubsubsec` by `\smallskip`. This provides some form of consistency. You could use the same for all.

---

If you want to stick to [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol), using a 3-column layout for the 1-column usage is also possible:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol

\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill\smallskip
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \centering {\bfseries Title 1} \par
  Description 1 \par
  \columnbreak
  {\bfseries Title 2} \par
  Description 2 \par
  \columnbreak
  {\bfseries Title 3} \par
  Description 3
\end{multicols}
\smallskip\noindent\hrulefill\smallskip
\begin{multicols}{3}
  \mbox{} \par \mbox{} \par
  \columnbreak
  \centering {\bfseries Title 4} \par
  Description 4
\end{multicols}
\smallskip\noindent\hrulefill\smallskip
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \centering {\bfseries Title 5} \par
  Description 5 \par
  \columnbreak
  {\bfseries Title 6} \par
  Description 5
\end{multicols}
\smallskip\noindent\hrulefill

\end{document}​
```

Comment: Very nice. So the answer is that it can't really be done. Either use the minor hack of using \multicols{3} with an empty first column, or instead switch to tabularx. I still label it as a hack, albeit a minor one, because it is no longer possible for the middle column to use more than one third of the width. This is not an issue in my case, so I am happy with that.

Comment: @Calaf: Sometimes, "fooling TeX" is the easiest. But this depends on your application. You can, of course, write your own environments and/or macros, if that seems like less of a hack to you.