# Spurious [?] vertical space introduced by multicols

Tags: spacing, multicol

In the example below, you'll notice, in the first box, a slight spurious vertical space before the text actually starts, and probably introduced by `multicols`. Do you know how to get rid of it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\begin{document}
\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
\begin{multicols}{3}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{multicols}%
\end{minipage}}%

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text
\end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

[image: illustration]

Comment: Answers are here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66977/9549

Comment: Related Question: [Spurious Vertical Space Introduced by multicols (Additional Case)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197130/spurious-vertical-space-introduced-by-multicols-follow-up).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to have the first lines at the same height as in normal setting, `multicol` sets `\splittopskip` to `\topskip`. This means that TeX will add glue equal to `\topskip-<height of first line>` above each column, ensuring they will be at the same reciprocal height, unless it's bigger than `\topskip` (in this case zero glue would be inserted).

In your setting, the added glue above each column is 3.84921pt (10pt minus the height of a “t”, because the standard value of `\topskip` is 10pt, with the `10pt` class option).

You can zero this added space by setting `\topskip` to a more sensible value, for instance the height of a capital letter.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}

\begin{document}
\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\setlength{\topskip}{\fontcharht\font`B }
\begin{multicols}{3}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cannot `\topskip` be set to `0pt`?

Comment: @karlkoeller No; the top lines wouldn't be necessarily vertically aligned to each other, because their distance from the top would depend only on the respective heights.

Answer (score 2):

The problem doesn't come from multicol itself :

The minipage environment eat all space around multicol, and the fcolorbox add some spurious space :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{3mm}\setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}%
\setlength{\multicolsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\begin{multicols}{2}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{multicols}

\hrule
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{multicols}
\end{minipage}}

\noindent\fcolorbox{red}{red!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me that there is a slightly bad interaction between `multicols` and `fcolorbox`.