# Spurious Vertical Space Introduced by multicols (Additional Case)

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, multicol, enumitem

This seems to be a duplicate of [Spurious [?] vertical space introduced by multicols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161966/spurious-vertical-space-introduced-by-multicols), but the solution from there does not seen to work for me.  Basically I want the case of using `multicols` to *not* change the vertical spacing between the intro text and the list. The output on the right is using `multicols`:

[image]

There is also additional space following the `multicols` environment.

### Notes:

- The `minipage` environment was used to illustrate the problem. I don *not* believe that that is affecting the additional vertical space issue.
- The `tikz` package is used *only* to highlight the spacing issue.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns

%\setlength{\multicolbaselineskip}{0pt}% Seems to have no effect


\begin{document} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\linewidth}
    The following are examples of numbers:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 0ne,
            \item $\pi$,
            \item $2+3i$,
            and
            \item $0$.
        \end{itemize}%
    Some text following.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%-------------------------
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\linewidth}
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161966/spurious-vertical-space-introduced-by-multicols
    %\setlength{\topskip}{\fontcharht\font`B }% Seems to have no effect
    The following are examples of numbers:
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 0ne,
            \item $\pi$,
            \item $2+3i$,
            \item $0$.
            \item Two,
            \item $e$,
            \item $2-3i$,
            and
            \item $-0$.
        \end{itemize}%
    \end{multicols}
    Some text following.
\end{minipage}%
% Following manually tweaked to show the problem.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [red]  (-11.5cm,-1.16cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
    \draw [blue] (-11.5cm,-1.86cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
    \draw [orange] (-11.5cm,-3.95cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

### Results (2014-08-25)

Here is the output I get from Frank Mittelbach's MWE (note that the spacing for the text following is not correct):

[image]

### Output from \listfiles:

I just updated *all* packages from TeXLive2014 prior to running the test. So, is one of my packages out of date, or is there a problem with the TeXLive2014 release:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    tikz.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142)
     pgf.sty    2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.25)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
 pgfmath.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
enumitem.sty    2011/09/28 v3.5.2 Customized lists
multicol.sty    2014/04/23 v1.8e multicolumn formatting (FMi)
etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
  omscmr.fd    1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
```

Comment: I have managed to put together a hack which inserts a negative `\vspace` before _and_ after the `multicols` environment by iterating and guessing at the correct spacing -- but feel that there must be a better way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a list such as `itemize` is placed at the start of a minipage its usual vertical spacing before the list is omitted.

Adding `multicols` the way you did it is producing a box around the `itemize` list just like a minipage and thus the `\topsep` is not added. Instead what you see is the `\multicolsep` which is added before and after the `multicol` environment.

In article class (10pt) `\topsep` has the value 8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt while `\multicolsep` is something like 12pt which accounts for (most) of the differences experienced. Thus

```
\setlength\multicolsep{\topsep}
```

should in theory fix your problem.

However, your example also showed a glitch in multicols handling of `\prevdepth` which accounts for 1.9994pt misalignment after the environment (happens happens only in "boxed" mode i.e. if the environment appears within a minipage or similar).

So additionally you need patch one of the multicol internals for now:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd\page@sofar{\kern-\dimen\tw@ \ifdim\dimen\tw@}
  {\kern-\dimen\tw@  \prevdepth\z@ \ifdim\dimen\tw@}
  {\typeout{Success!}}{\ERRORpatching}

\makeatother
```

With those two adjustements you should see the following:

[image]

As requested here is the full MWE, if that doesn't work at your end you may have an older version of `multicol` perhaps, this was run with version 2014/06/19 v1.8f.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\usepackage{multicol}
\raggedcolumns

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength\multicolsep{\topsep}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd\page@sofar{\kern-\dimen\tw@ \ifdim\dimen\tw@}
  {\kern-\dimen\tw@  \prevdepth\z@ \ifdim\dimen\tw@}
  {\typeout{Success!}}{\ERRORpatching}

\makeatother


\begin{document} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\linewidth}
    The following are examples of numbers:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 0ne,
            \item $\pi$,
            \item $2+3i$,
            and
            \item $0$.
        \end{itemize}%
    Some text following.
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%-------------------------
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.44\linewidth}
    %% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161966/spurious-vertical-space-introduced-by-multicols
    %\setlength{\topskip}{\fontcharht\font`B }% Seems to have no effect
    The following are examples of numbers:
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item 0ne,
            \item $\pi$,
            \item $2+3i$,
            \item $0$.
            \item Two,
            \item $e$,
            \item $2-3i$,
            and
            \item $-0$.
        \end{itemize}%
    \end{multicols}%
    Some text following.
\end{minipage}%
% Following manually tweaked to show the problem.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [red]  (-11.5cm,-1.16cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
    \draw [blue] (-11.5cm,-1.86cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
    \draw [orange] (-11.5cm,-3.95cm) -- ++(4.8in,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Upate

A fix for this issue was added to `multicol` 1.8g. The new version is now on CTAN and should show up on distributions with update capabilities in a few days (once Heiko gets around providing the tls package).

Note that a suitable setting for `\multicolsep` is still necessary (and will always be).

Comment: That does not seem to fix the problem for the text following. Can you post the full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). In the mean time I am trying to get to the bottom of why we are seeing different results.

Comment: Oh, and my actual use case is _not_ in a `minipage` (but within an `mdframed`) -- just in case that effects things. The `minipage` was used here just to show the misalignment.

Comment: I can't see how mdframed would act differently as it too produces a box as I recall. Anyway, you should get at least the same outcome for the MWE as given.

Comment: I have included the output and package info form `\listfiles` in the question. Not sure where the problem is.

Comment: The only noticeable difference is that you use multicol 1.8e while CTAN has 1.8f. And the change long for that version seems relevant: 2014-06-19  Frank Mittelbach  <latex-bugs@latex-project.org>

 * multicol.dtx: color-leak fix introduced a spacing problem in boxed mode
 as the added color commands were hiding any space at the bottom of the box
 material (which thus didn't get discarded)

Comment: Hmmm, I am not seeing any package that needing to be update via the `TeXLive Utility`.

Comment: I don't know how TeXLive does this, but fact is that on CTAN multicol is on 1.8f and yours is 1.8e which has a spacing issue with boxed mode. You can always download the dtx manually and run multicol.ins to get the sty file. Not very convenient perhaps but  ...

Comment: @PeterGrill I would appreciate if you could check that this is fixing your issue

Comment: Am out of town right now, will look into it when I get back later this week.